# Transpose Data coming from SQL Server query into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

I have following query to get data from multiple tables

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
   dbo.tblProduct.PK AS PRODUCT_PK, dbo.tblProduct.PRODUCT_NAME, 
   dbo.tblProductSubComponent.SUB_COMPONENT_PK, 
   dbo.tblComponent.COMPONENT_NAME, dbo.tblSubComponent.SUB_COMPONENT_NAME
FROM         
   dbo.tblProductComponent 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.tblComponent 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.tblSubComponent 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.tblComponentSubComponent ON dbo.tblSubComponent.PK = dbo.tblComponentSubComponent.SUB_COMPONENT_PK 
       ON dbo.tblComponent.PK = dbo.tblComponentSubComponent.COMPONENT_PK 
       ON dbo.tblProductComponent.COMPONENT_PK = dbo.tblComponent.PK 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.tblProductSubComponent ON dbo.tblSubComponent.PK = dbo.tblProductSubComponent.SUB_COMPONENT_PK 
FULL OUTER JOIN
   dbo.tblProduct ON dbo.tblProductSubComponent.PRODUCT_PK = dbo.tblProduct.PK AND dbo.tblProductComponent.PRODUCT_PK = dbo.tblProduct.PK
ORDER BY 
    PRODUCT_PK
```

The result is

[image: The result]

and now I want to show data in gridview like this

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind.. I solved it myself. Created a stored procedure to fetch data and stored it in table variable and then used alter column query to add my rows as column of temporary table.
After creating the temporary table, I looped through each component and inserted record for each component and sub-component.